# Can you stop Webpack from bundling unreachable modules because of .env file

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, webpack

So for example:

```
import axios from 'axios'
 if(process.env.USE_AXIOS) {
    axios.get("/");
 }
```

in this Axios should not be bundled from Webpack.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What makes `axios` unreachable? You're still importing it. What about using dynamic imports (although it may still always be included in the webpack output)?

Comment: See https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/ for more info about how webpack / terser is able to remove "unreachable code."

Comment: it wourd be unreachable when `USE_AXIOS` would be false

Comment: @DerDorius only the function call `axios.get` is unreachable. The module itself is still reachable.

Comment: @evolutionxbox so we are trying to build a modular Electron App and want the modules to be dynamicly compiled in based on the .env file 

is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably couple of ways to handle conditional compilation, but one I know it works is to use dynamic imports

```js
// Just to not throw an exception in the snippet
const process = {
 env:{
   USE_AXIOS: false
 }
}
// ------------------------------------------------






// Solution
if (process.env.USE_AXIOS) {
  import('axios').then(({default: axios}) => {
    if ('get' in axios) {
      console.log('axios in use');
    }
  });
}
```

full code example is here [webpack-conditional-complation](https://github.com/spamshaker/webpack-conditional-complation)

you can examine a produced code

- here is an [axios](https://github.com/spamshaker/webpack-conditional-complation/blob/master/dist/axois.js) bundled in separated file
- here is a compiled ./src/include-axios-base-on-env.js to [with-axios.js](https://github.com/spamshaker/webpack-conditional-complation/blob/master/dist/with-axios.js) with flag USE_AXIOS=true
- here is a compiled ./src/include-axios-base-on-env.js to [without-axios.js](https://github.com/spamshaker/webpack-conditional-complation/blob/master/dist/without-axios.js) with flag USE_AXIOS=false